# Mockito fails with "Argument(s) are different" but debugger shows differently

Tags: java, mockito

I am testing a method, which uses Mockito mocked objects. When I run the test, Mockito tells me that the parameters passed into the argument are different than expected. If I set a breakpoint within the method I am testing, the argument that it is called with is actually what I expect. This method only gets called once. Why is Mockito reporting something different from what I see with the debugger, and how can I fix this?

Here is the test:

```
@Test
public void addExclusivePermutationsTest() {
    Permutation p1 = mock(Permutation.class);

    PermutationBuilder pb = new PermutationBuilder();

    when(p1.applyPermutations(anySetOf(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(Collections.singleton("abc123"));

    pb.addExclusivePermutations(p1);
    pb.permute("test");

    verify(p1).applyPermutations(new HashSet<>(
            Collections.singletonList("test")));
}
```

The test is pretty simple. `Permutation` is an interface that contains the method definition `Set<String> applyPermutations(Set<String>)`. When that method is called on `p1`, I tell Mockito to return a set containing `[abc123]`.

The `addExclusivePermutations(p1)` call simply adds `p1` to an `ExclusivePermutation` object that contains a list of `Permutation` objects. `ExclusivePermutation` is an implementor of `Permutation` so its `applyPermutations` method looks like this:

```
public Set<String> applyPermutations(final Set<String> stringPermutations) {
    Set<String> exclusivePermutations = new HashSet<>();

    for (Permutation permutation : permutationList) {
        exclusivePermutations.addAll(permutation.applyPermutations(stringPermutations));
    }

    return exclusivePermutations;
}
```

The above method is called inside `permute("test")`. The string `"test"` is converted into a `Set`, and passed into the above method. The above method is what calls `applyPermutations` on `p1`. When I look at this method with a debugger, `stringPermutations` contains only `[test]`, as I expect it to, and is passed directly into `p1`. Then `p1` returns `[abc123]` because it's mocked, and the above method joins it with `stringPermutations` to return `[test, abc123]`. So for some reason, Mockito is saying that `stringPermutations` is not `[test]` as the debugger shows, but instead what the method returns.

Finally, here is the error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
permutation.applyPermutations(
    [test]
);
-> at PermutationBuilderTest$AddExclusivePermutationTests.addExclusivePermutationsTest(PermutationBuilderTest.java:87)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
permutation.applyPermutations(
    [abc123, test]
);
```

One last note (for those of you who are still reading). If I bypass `ExclusivePermuation` by copying `ExclusivePermutation.applyPermutation()` and putting it directly inside `PermutationBuilder`, the test passes. It is a mystery...

**EDIT:**

So I've narrowed it down a bit. In `PermutationBuilder` I have this method:

```
public Set<String> permute(String s) {
    for (Modifier modifier : modifierList) {
        s = modifier.applyModification(s);
    }

    Set<String> stringPermutations = new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(s));

    for (Permutation permutation : permutationList) {
        Set<String> result = permutation.applyPermutations(stringPermutations);
        stringPermutations.addAll(result);
    }

    return stringPermutations;
}
```

After I assign result, Mockito says that the method was called with `[test]`. However, when I step to the next line to add it to `stringPermutations`, it changes to `[abc123, test]`. You can see this in the two screenshots below (look at the bottom at the `arguments` array):

[image: After getting result]

[image]

Comment: Did you try `verify(p1).applyPermutations(Mockito.eq(new HashSet<>(
            Collections.singletonList("test"))));` ?

Comment: @RahulSharma I have tried that, but as I expected it didn't help. The issue is not that the Sets contain the same elements, but are not being evaluated to equal. The issue is that Mockito says the sets contain different elements, but the debugger says otherwise, and I need to figure out why that is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're modifying the set that you're using as the argument.

That is, in the code

```
Set<String> stringPermutations = new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(s));

for (Permutation permutation : permutationList) {
    Set<String> result = permutation.applyPermutations(stringPermutations);
    stringPermutations.addAll(result);
}
```

You create the `stringPermutations` object, and add `test` to it. You now have a collection with one element.

You then call `permutation.applyPermutations`, and add the result of that to `stringPermutations`.

`stringPermutations` now contains `test` *and* `abc123`.

What is almost certainly going on here is that Mockito is *not* cloning the arguments (that would be... tricky to get right), and it is simply retaining a reference to the object(s) passed in.

Since you mutate `stringPermutations` *after* calling the method, Mockito thinks you called the method with a collection containing `test` *and* `abc123`, because that's what's in the collection when it attempts to verify the assertion. The simplest way to fix this is to not modify the collection after you've passed it into the method.

A solution could be:

```
Set<String> stringPermutations = new HashSet<>();

for (Permutation permutation : permutationList) {
    Set<String> result = permutation.applyPermutations(Collections.singletonList(s));
    stringPermutations.addAll(result);
}

stringPermutations.addAll(Collections.singletonList(s));
```

If you *really* need `stringPermutations` to contain both elements.

Comment: You are spot on! Great catch, I was completely stumped. Thanks!

Comment: While this is a right and explains what's going on, changing production code for the same of the unit test and mocks doesn't make a lot of sense. Is there any solution to capture with copying the incoming objects?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues opened for the same matter in the mockito github:

- [Modifying invocation arguments in custom answer causes verification of those arguments fail #1153](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1153)
- [Capturing arguments when calling verify, not when real method executed #1287](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1287)

So, first of all, creators consider it as a limitation of a framework as copying arguments at call-time would affect the performance and there is no common way to do a deep-copy anyway.

Secondly, the statement above explains what you should do in such situations: you need to clone arguments on your own. I haven't tried, but here are the suggested ways:

- org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.ClonesArguments
- Do a manual copy in the doAnswer and verify it instead of captor

However, when I used ClonesArguments for my use case:

```
doAnswer((invocation) -> {
    new ClonesArguments().answer(invocation);
    // in my case situation is different and instead of modifying invocation
    // my argument is the same collection 4 times with different elements
    // in your case it may or may not work
    // maybe you will have to copy paste and update their code
    return myAnswer;
})
```

I see in debug that elements of my collection are copied, but at the verify stage I still see only the most recent value, so didn't work for me.